# Using ThreadPoolExecutor with Flask results in too many threads

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, pool, executor

I'm working on a small flask app.

The idea is when a user clicks on "update all", a utility class submits all defined servers to the updater which calls each server's "get()" method.

route.py:

```
@servers.route('/update/<id>')
def update(id):

  servers = UcxServer.query.filter(id != None)


  def update_server(server):
    server.create_ucx()
    server.update_ucx()
    return threading.current_thread().name, server 

  with Pool(max_workers=5) as executor:
    start = timer()

    for name, server in executor.map(update_server, servers):
        print("%s %s" % (name, server)) # print results
        db.session.add(server)
        db.session.commit()


  print('time:', timer() - start)




  flash('All servers have been updated')
  return redirect(url_for('servers.index'))
```

The problem appears when this button is used multiple times in that it keeps spawning new threads. If I have 5 servers, first time I use the button I will get 5 threads. Next time 10, and so on.

What is the proper way to do this thread management so that I don't end up with a million threads after the apps has been up for a spell?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're making a new `Pool` each time through, which would explain the symptom - but it's hard to tell as your indenting seems broken, please edit to fix it.

Comment: Indenting seems alright to me. It looks like you are correct about creating a new pool with every request. Does this at least mean the previous pool has been shut down? Or am I leaking threads?

Comment: The `with` statement **should** clean things up properly, assuming that `Pool` is a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` -- so if that's right and so's your indentation, then I can't guess.  However I don't see how the indentation can possibly be right, with the `def` and `if` in lines 2-3 aligned with each other for example.

Comment: Alex, thanks again for the reply. You are correct and I removed the if statement. 

The with statement indeed should take care of closing the threads.

I could try moving it out of the routes, but then I wouldn't know how to update each of the objects. My query returns all of the servers.

If I were to just pass that list of server objects to an external multi-threaded function, I have no idea how to commit each server to the db once it comes back.

Comment: After using threading.enumerate() I can see that the threads are being closed. It appears that the executor.map just is not reusing the thread names, but creating new names for each run. Is this a problem?

Comment: Shouldn't be, there's an unlimited supply of thread names!-)

Comment: If you want to use concurrent.futures with Flask you should try the Flask-Executor extension